How to fill gap between pressure-treated lumber?
I built some 6' wide window wells for egress windows because I couldn't find corrugated wells big enough. The outside of the well is covered up to 4 planks high (all but the top plank) in black plastic to protect against potential rot from wet dirt sitting up against it. The last plank at the top has a gap in it where dirt falls through on occasion and I want to stop that so weeds don't eventually grow in my window well.
Should I use caulk (clear/black) to fill the cracks on both sides? I'm hoping some of you more seasoned diy-ers have some pro tips for me.
window well wide shot

space between lumber


caulk or roofing sealer could work.

Just line the outside of the "fence" with geotextile fabric as you fill it.  Depending how long your pieces are, you could just lay the fabric over the top of the fence, or temporarily staple the top edge of the fabric to the top of the fence.  Overlap 6" on the groud outside the fence before starting to fill.

@Huesmann I bought black roofing silicone but if I wedged fabric in between the two pieces of wood that would also work. I think I'll go with that. Thanks for sharing!

No, don't wedge.  Just lay a sheet of geotextile on the back of the wall.
